# checkbox data not sent by jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#result input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e){
        var chkval = 0
          if($('#result').is(':checked')){
            chkval  = 1;
          }
   $.ajax({
       url: "nsmsr.php",
       type: "POST",
       data:{'checkboxvalue':chkval},
       cache:false,
     });

   });  

});
</script>



<input type="checkbox" checked='checked'  id="result">
```

I'm using this script to send the checkbox value to a php file, but nothing get posted. I searched a lot but nothing helped me to fix the bug.

Comment: what is the `value` you expect from that code?

Comment: if checked i want to sent 1 else 0.. that's it.

Comment: your selector seems wrong `$("#result input[type='checkbox']")`, use `$("input[type='checkbox']")`

Comment: but if i've more than one checkbox in the page..then its gonna be a issue right?

Comment: so $("#result[type='checkbox']"), but you should have one id per page

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't quite focused before, indeed the rest of the answerers are right, you are not binding your `click` event to the correct element. Your code should be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#result').click(function(e){
      var chkval = 0;
          if($('#result').is(':checked')){
            chkval  = 1;
          }
   $.ajax({
       url: "nsmsr.php",
       type: "POST",
       data:{'checkboxvalue':chkval},
       cache:false,
     });

   });  

});
</script>



<input type="checkbox" checked='checked'  id="result">
```

Comment: can u add this to my existing code

Comment: Why would this work? The OP's code doesn't handle the checkbox's value anywhere.

Comment: tried this, but no result

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong, `$("#result input[type='checkbox']")` attempts to select a checkbox that is a descendant of `#result` which does not exist. Just use `$("#result")`.

```
$("#result").click(function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

`"#result input[type='checkbox']"` refers to a *child* of `#result`, not to `#result` itself. Since it's an id you should just use

```
$("#result").click(function(e){
```

If you want to attach the event to all checkboxes on the page:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e){
    var chkval = 0
      if($( this ).is(':checked')){
        chkval  = 1;
      }
....
```

Comment: I've more than one checkbox.

Comment: I just updated the answer. Use `$( this )` to refer to the checkbox that was just clicked.

Comment: Reading between the lines, do you have multiple checkboxes with the same id? Ids should be unique.

Comment: nopes it still not working

Comment: You must post more of your code. What I have works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FMy35/